# Windows firewall - opening ports by specifying .exe

Tags: firewall, port, windows-firewall

Normally, you open ports by specifying port number and the protocol - either TCP or UDP. However, Windows allows me to add exceptions by specifying the executable file. How does it work? What happens under the hood when I select, for example, 'mygame.exe'?

I'm thinking how is it implemented in the OS. Windows would have to keep track of the programs which declared they listen on a specific port X. Then, as a packet arrives, it checks it destination port, next it checks if any of the programs on the exceptions list listens on that port and if mygame.exe is there, it forwards the packet to mygame.exe. If there's no matching program on the exception list, then it checks the list of open ports. If the destination port is not on that list, the packet is ignoerd.

Is this how it works?

Comment: I don't think you can have 2 different processes listening on the same port  The terminology listening on a port is the terminology but is misleading. What it really is, is a field within the 'packet'(and I use the term packet in the general sense as including all the fields).. And so the port is like an id that indicates to the OS what process to give it to. The process that is said to be listening on that port. And yeah I guess if no process sees the packet, then that packet was dropped or as good as dropped  / effectively dropped.

Comment: @barlop well, of course no two different processes can listen on the same port at the same time (that's what ports are for anyway). Two web browers can listen on the same port 80, but each web brower instance is bound to a different local port. So when the server sends a response to my Chrome browser, it sets the source port to 80, and destination port to the randomly generated port created when I made a request to the server. At the same time, Firefox can listen on port 80, which means it will accept TCP packets with source port set to 80, but the destination port of the packet sent by server

Comment: will be different than of the packets that are adressed to my Chrome browser.

Comment: @user4205580: Web browsers don't listen on any port. "Listening" on a port does *not* mean accepting traffic where the source port is set to 80. Listening means it has bound a local port to accept unsolicited inbound traffic.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq See the accepted answer here. So listening on a port X means having a local port bound to it to accept inbound traffic? Yeah, that's what I meant, I just wasn't clear enough. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190176/how-does-port-number-really-work-in-tcp

Comment: @user4205580  listening on a port, is for accepting incoming connections, rather than generally incoming or inbound traffic.Once a connection is made, whether it's an outgoing connection, or an incoming connection,the traffic's then both ways.So 4example,if u ever use a linux firewall called iptables,then u see traffic in,includes traffic coming in during an outgoin connection.n whetherA connection is incoming or outgoing is purely a q of who initiates what's called the tcp 3 way handshake.(note- iptables can use its own definitions eg it defines connection differently but re in/out it's fine)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how it works. [Microsoft suggests](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/risks-allowing-programs-through-firewall#1TC=windows-7) actually to do it this way:

> When you add a program to the list of allowed programs in a firewall,
>   or when you open a firewall port, you allow a particular program to
>   send information to or from your computer through the firewall.
>   Allowing a program to communicate through a firewall (sometimes called
>   unblocking) is like punching a hole in the firewall.
>
> Each time you open a port or allow a program to communicate through a
>   firewall, your computer becomes a bit less secure. The more allowed
>   programs or open ports your firewall has, the more opportunities there
>   are for hackers or malicious software to use one of those openings to
>   spread a worm, access your files, or use your computer to spread
>   malicious software to others.
>
> **It's generally safer to add a program to the list of allowed programs
>   than to open a port**. If you open a port, it stays open until you close
>   it, whether or not a program is using it. If you add a program to the
>   list of allowed programs, the "hole" is open only when needed for a
>   particular communication.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking how is it implemented in the OS. Windows would have to
>   keep track of the programs which declared they listen on a specific
>   port X. Then, as a packet arrives, it checks it destination port, next
>   it checks if any of the programs on the exceptions list listens on
>   that port and if mygame.exe is there, it forwards the packet to
>   mygame.exe. If there's no matching program on the exception list, then
>   it checks the list of open ports. If the destination port is not on
>   that list, the packet is ignoerd.
>
> Is this how it works?

No, this isn't how it works. It's actually simpler than that:

- The firewall doesn't deal with forwarding packets to programs - Winsock does
- There is only one set of rules
- There is no "order" in which rules are checked

The way the Windows firewall works is described in detail in this [Microsoft technet article.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755604(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_architecture)

> When an incoming packet reaches your computer, Windows Firewall
>   inspects the packet and determines whether it meets criteria specified
>   in the Windows Firewall exceptions list (the combination of the NAT
>   Mapping Table and the Windows Firewall rules store). If the packet
>   matches an entry in the list, Windows Firewall passes the packet to
>   the TCP/IP protocol for further processing. If the packet does not
>   match an entry in the list, Windows Firewall silently discards the
>   packet and creates an entry in the Windows Firewall log file (if the
>   log file is enabled on the Log Settings dialog box in Windows
>   Firewall). The entries in the exceptions list can consist of program
>   names, system service names, TCP ports, and UDP ports. There is no way
>   to create an entry in the exceptions list based on the IP Protocol
>   field in the IP header.

Basically, in default mode the firewall only really cares about denying packets. If it doesn't match a rule, the firewall drops it. Otherwise, the firewall just does nothing, allowing Winsock to forward it to the relevant program.

Comment: It doesn't answer my main question - TCP packets keep source and destination port numbers, not the name of .exe. How does Windows know it can send the packet to my program that's on exceptions list? It must keep track of what programs listen on given ports.

Comment: @user4205580: That's the job of Winsock and the rest of the TCP/IP stack. The whole point of ports in the first place is to help identify what program it's going to. The article linked to in my answer has a picture of the different components and how they interact.